# "the repeated bus stops/ the recurrent bus stops"

Tags: adjectives

**the repeated/recurrent stops**

I can't find a good adjective to describe the fact that the stops are many, following one after another at small distance (tens of meters), like in front of an airport. **Frequent** it's too vague.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean stops for different buses, or for the same bus that keeps stopping? If the former, is an adjective appropriate? How about **a row of bus stops** or **a line of bus stops**?

Comment: In front of an airport for each terminal there is a bus stop at one hundred meters, maybe less, from the precedent. That I refer to. A bus does stop for each terminal at the airport. I will consider your suggestions, among others. Thanks, Weather Vane!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to say the stops are **too close together**.  Neither *repeated* nor *recurrent* seem to fit this context.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions are not single adjectives but maybe still helpful:

- *many bus stops in close succession*
- *many bus stops closely after each other*